# How to make two 3d plots slide on each other surface using python?

Tags: python, animation, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I have the code in python for two 3d plots and I want that those two plots to slide on each other surface and to see when they overlap each other, when there are gaps or when they only touch each other. To make two 3D plots slide together as part of an interactive visualization, I can use Plotly's animation capabilities. This would allow me to smoothly transition between different views of the plots. Basically, this is the suggestion by chatgpt and I don't know how to make it possible in the code below.

```
fig = go.Figure(
    layout=dict(
        template="ggplot2",
        margin=dict(l=50, r=10, b=50, t=50),
        font=dict(family="Computer Modern", size=12, color="black"),
        width=1000,
        height=800,
        scene=dict(aspectmode="cube"),
        legend=dict(
            title="", orientation="h", yanchor="bottom", x=0, y=1.0, xanchor="left"
        ),
    )
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter3d(
        x=W_vals["x"],
        y=W_vals["y"],
        z=W_vals["value"],
        text=W_vals["value"],
        texttemplate="%{text:.2f}",
        mode="markers+text",
        marker=dict(size=3, color="black"),
        name="W Values",
        showlegend=True,
        
    )
)
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(
        x=W_vals["x"],
        y=W_vals["y"],
        z=W_vals["value"],))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Surface(
        x=W_pivot.columns,
        y=W_pivot.index,
        z=W_pivot.values,
        name="W Surface",
        opacity=0.8,
        showlegend=True, 
        colorscale="Viridis",
        cmid=np.mean(W_pivot.values)
    )
)

fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=data.values, name="Lotus Surface", colorscale="Greys", showlegend=True,visible="legendonly",
))

fig.show()
```

[image]

```
fig = go.Figure(
    layout=dict(
        template="ggplot2",
        margin=dict(l=50, r=10, b=50, t=50, pad=0),
        font=dict(family="Computer Modern", size=12, color="black"),
        width=800,
        height=800,
        scene=dict(aspectmode="cube"),
    )
)

fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=data.values))
fig.update_traces(
    contours_z=dict(
        show=True, usecolormap=True, highlightcolor="limegreen", project_z=True
    )
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide a sample of your data, or the actual data if it's easily retrievable or reproducible? it's also a little hard to tell what you're asking, but if you add both surfaces as traces, you'll be able to tell when they're overlapping or touching by hovering over the figure. to be honest, I don't understand what `To make two 3D plots slide together as part of an interactive visualization, I can use Plotly's animation capabilities` means exactly – was this the suggestion by ChatGPT?

Comment: I can provide you with the data and the whole code. That part that you have marked was the response by chatgpt about my problem. I can also provide you with an example.

Comment: if you can include the data in your question as either a link or something that can be copy+pasted, that would help us reproduce your figures – thanks!

Comment: @DerekO I don't know how to insert data here.

Comment: @DerekO   the link: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3wtcepixklx95g4c6w41d/LotusLeaf3.csv?rlkey=k2vyk4q80pxw25006xauh4axb&dl=0                                                                https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/zy7fmnb6l7jxrydguci7d/W_values_E-1_Width-5_Length-5.csv?rlkey=mn0zuz849awmnpw03lz2s1xpd&dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for this project and the code I have posted before should be in the end (I haven't added that code because I have posted before):

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pickle






# update the model to ensure it is a smooth surface, adjust the obj function
data = pd.read_csv("LotusLeaf3.csv", header=None)
#data = data / 92.808
A = data[0].to_numpy()
B = data[1].to_numpy()

W_vals = pd.read_csv("W_values_E=1_Width=5_Length=5.csv", index_col=0)
W_vals[["variable", "x", "y"]] = W_vals["variable"].str.split("_", expand=True)
W_pivot = W_vals.pivot(index="y", columns="x", values="value")

W_vals.head()
print(W_vals)






z = W_vals["value"].to_numpy()

x = np.unique(W_vals['x'])
x = np.sort(x.astype(int))
y = np.unique(W_vals['y'])
y = np.sort(y.astype(int))
z = z.reshape(np.max(x)+1, np.max(y)+1)
z = z.T
surface_plot = go.Surface(z=z, x=x, y=y)

# scatter_plot = go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode='markers', marker=dict(size=5))

fig = go.Figure(data=surface_plot)

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=800,
    height=800,
)

# fig.add_trace(
#     go.Scatter3d(
#         x=W_vals["x"],
#         y=W_vals["y"],
#         z=W_vals["value"],
#         text=W_vals["value"],
#         texttemplate="%{text:.2f}",
#         mode="markers+text",
#         marker=dict(size=3, color="black"),
#         name="W Values",
#         showlegend=True,
    
#     )
# )
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=W_vals.values, name="Lotus Surface",
                       colorscale="Greys", showlegend=True,visible="legendonly",))


fig.show()










np.sort(np.unique(W_vals['x']).astype(int))




z.T






fig = go.Figure(
    layout=dict(
        template="ggplot2",
        margin=dict(l=50, r=10, b=50, t=50),
        font=dict(family="Computer Modern", size=12, color="black"),
        width=1000,
        height=800,
        scene=dict(aspectmode="cube"),
        legend=dict(
            title="", orientation="h", yanchor="bottom", x=0, y=1.0, 
                   xanchor="left"
        ),
    )
)
# fig.add_trace(
#     go.Scatter3d(
#         x=x,
#         y=y,
#         z=z,
#         text=z,
#         texttemplate="%{text:.2f}",
#         mode="markers+text",
#         marker=dict(size=3, color="black"),
#         name="W Values",
#         showlegend=True,
    
#     )
# )
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter3d(
        x=W_vals["x"],
        y=W_vals["y"],
        z=W_vals["value"],
        text=W_vals["value"],
        texttemplate="%{text:.2f}",
        mode="markers+text",
        marker=dict(size=3, color="black"),
        name="W Values",
        showlegend=True,
    
    )
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: can you add this into your question instead of as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a matter of adding both surfaces as traces to the same figure. However, the x and y ranges of the two surfaces are very different – the range of the surface constructed from `W_vals` is `[0, 4] x [0, 4]`, and the range of the surface constructed from `data` is `[0, 1460] x [0, 2669]` so if you want both surfaces to be visible, you probably need to scale some of the values up or down. For example, you can multiply the x- and y-values in W_vals by a scaling factor of `1460/4` and `2669/4`, respectively (though I am really just guessing here, I don't know what this data is or what the use case is).

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pickle


# update the model to ensure it is a smooth surface, adjust the obj function
data = pd.read_csv("LotusLeaf3.csv", header=None)

W_vals = pd.read_csv("W_values_E=1_Width=5_Length=5.csv", index_col=0)
W_vals[["variable", "x", "y"]] = W_vals["variable"].str.split("_", expand=True)

## rescale W_vals
# x = columns, y = rows
x_min, x_max = data.columns[0], data.columns[-1]
y_min, y_max = data.index[0], data.index[-1]

x_scale_factor = x_max / float(W_vals['x'].max())
y_scale_factor = y_max / float(W_vals['y'].max())
W_vals['x'] = x_scale_factor*W_vals['x'].astype(float)
W_vals['y'] = x_scale_factor*W_vals['y'].astype(float)

W_pivot = W_vals.pivot(index="y", columns="x", values="value")

fig = go.Figure(
    layout=dict(
        template="ggplot2",
        margin=dict(l=50, r=10, b=50, t=50),
        font=dict(family="Computer Modern", size=12, color="black"),
        width=1000,
        height=800,
        scene=dict(aspectmode="cube"),
        legend=dict(
            title="", orientation="h", yanchor="bottom", x=0, y=1.0, xanchor="left"
        ),
    )
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter3d(
        x=W_vals["x"],
        y=W_vals["y"],
        z=W_vals["value"],
        text=W_vals["value"],
        texttemplate="%{text:.2f}",
        mode="markers+text",
        marker=dict(size=3, color="black"),
        name="W Values",
        showlegend=True,
        
    )
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Surface(
        x=W_pivot.columns,
        y=W_pivot.index,
        z=W_pivot.values,
        name="W Surface",
        opacity=0.8,
        showlegend=True, 
        colorscale="Viridis",
        cmid=np.mean(W_pivot.values)
    )
)

## constrain the data to the surface
# x_min, x_max = int(W_vals['x'].min()), int(W_vals['x'].max())
# y_min, y_max = int(W_vals['y'].min()), int(W_vals['y'].max())

# data_subset = data.iloc[y_min:y_max, x_min:x_max]

# add data

fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=data.values, name="Lotus Surface", colorscale="Greys", showlegend=True,
))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: can you give the email address to sent my data via wetransfer?